# Error in Swift, Cannot assign to a literal value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been trying to make an if statment in swift that checks if a label equals the same text. Like this,

```
if splitLabel.text = 1.0 = true {
        var tipTotal = percentage * Double((billAmount)!)
```

but I get the error `Cannot assign to a literal value`

This is in Swift with Xcode 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some guesswork since there are two assignment operators (`=`) in the statement.

1. You can't compare a string (`splitLabel.text`) to a number (`1.0`). They are not the same types so can not be compared.
2. The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`, the latter is the assignment operator.
3. There are two assignment operators (`=`) in the statement.

Probably you want something like:

```
if splitLabel.text == "1.0" {
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign "true", I think you made a typo there

Use this code instead

```
if splitLabel.text ==  "1.0" {
        var tipTotal = percentage * Double((billAmount)!)
}
```

Comment: ? I'm a bit confused what do you mean?

Comment: What did you want to achieve by 'if splitLabel.text = 1.0 = true'??

Comment: I needed to find out if the text did or did not equal "1.0".

Comment: Then use 'if splitLabel.text == "1.0" '

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what the problem was, and how this answer resolves them, instead of simply providing correct code.